# Why is my sorted file bigger?

Tags: text-processing

I have a 2958616 byte text file. When I run  `sort < file.txt | uniq > sorted-file.txt`, I get a 3213965 byte text file. Why is my sorted text file bigger?

You can download the text files [here](https://wb9688.stackstorage.com/index.php/s/MErnK3Wf3Dn1BJM).

Comment: Interesting. These are old and tried tools. They should not make files bigger, only smaller.

Comment: Are you operating on any kind of compressed file system or with spare files that do not occupy space for large empty areas inside them?

Comment: @ByteCommander No.

Comment: When I apply the command you gave above to your downloaded `file.txt`, the output is only 2942389 bytes large, about 16 kB smaller than the original. Are you sure you ran exactly the command you gave us? Please try running it again.

Comment: I'm exactly running that command. I still get a bigger output. When I run it on another computer, I get a smaller output.

Comment: Interesting is that examining your and my output file with `wc`, I learn that they both have the same line and word count, but yours is bigger in bytes:  `271576  271576 2942389 my-sorted.txt` and `271576  271576 3213965 sorted-file.txt`.

Comment: Your output file has `\r\n` line endings, whereas the input file has `\n` line endings. Perhaps you should set your locale differently. Try `LC_ALL=C` in front of each command.

Comment: @meuh That was it! Could you add that as an answer?

Comment: Hang on, the *locale* affects this? What locale are you using? What's the output of `locale`? Are you sure you didn't create the file on some other system?

Comment: Looks like the original file has been mangled for the character sequence `o-o` as in `co-ordinator` which becomes `coM-CM-6rdinator` (in `cat -vet` output). So it gets recognised as non-unix by sort??

Comment: @meuh that wouldn't make it add `\r`. Also, it doesn't do so on my Arch. It might be a bug in Ubuntu's `sort` or `uniq` I guess.

Comment: The utf8 char sequence in the original file is for `coördinator` and similar words.

Comment: But it only contains the following characters: `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

Comment: `sed '/^[a-z]*$/d' < file.txt  | wc -l`  gave me 305 lines.

Comment: Your file also contains `â ê î ñ ô ö öö û` those aren't in the ASCII set.

Comment: You might be interested in the -u parameter of most sort versions.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

While your original file has lines that end with `\n`, your sorted file has `\r\n`. The addition of the `\r` is what changes the size.

To illustrate, here's what happens when I run your command on my Linux system:

```
$ sort < file.txt | uniq > sorted-file.linux.txt
$ ls -l file.txt sorted-file.linux.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 2958616 Jul 10 12:11 file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 2942389 Jul 10 15:15 sorted-file.linux.txt
$ wc -l file.txt sorted-file.linux.txt 
273882 file.txt
271576 sorted-file.linux.txt
```

As you can see, the sorted de-duped file is a few lines shorter and, consequently, a few bytes smaller. Your file, however, is different:

```
$ wc -l sorted-file.linux.txt sorted-file.txt 
271576 sorted-file.linux.txt
271576 sorted-file.txt
```

The two files have exactly the same number of lines, but:

```
$ ls -l file.txt sorted-file.linux.txt sorted-file.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 2958616 Jul 10 12:11 file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 2942389 Jul 10 15:15 sorted-file.linux.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 3213965 Jul 10 12:11 sorted-file.txt
```

The `sorted-file.txt`, the one I downloaded from your link, is larger. If we now examine the first line, we can see the extra `\r`:

```
$ head -n1 sorted-file.txt | od -c
0000000   a  \r  \n
0000003
```

Which aren't present in the one I created on Linux:

```
$ head -n1 sorted-file.linux.txt | od -c
0000000   a  \n
0000002
```

If we now remove the `\r` from your file:

```
$ tr -d '\r' < sorted-file.txt > new-sorted-file.txt
```

We get the expected result, a file that is smaller than the original, just like the one I created on my system:

```
$ ls -l sorted-file.linux.txt new-sorted-file.txt file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 2958616 Jul 10 12:11 file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 2942389 Jul 10 15:19 new-sorted-file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 2942389 Jul 10 15:15 sorted-file.linux.txt
```

Comment: How come sort command added \r to the resulting file? Isn't the combination of \r plus \n a Windows thing?

Comment: @TulainsCórdova that's a very good question. I have no idea. I am assuming the OP did this in a non-native environment but I don't know. And yes, `\r\n` line endings are a Windows thing.

Answer (score 25):

`hexdump` reveals it!

```
$ hexdump -cn 32 file.txt 
0000000   a   d   h   d  \n   a   d   s   l  \n   a   m   v   b  \n   a
0000010   o   v  \n   a   o   w  \n   a   r   o   b  \n   a   s   f   a
0000020

$ hexdump -cn 32 my-sorted.txt 
0000000   a  \n   a   a  \n   a   a   a  \n   a   a   d  \n   a   a   d
0000010   s  \n   a   a   f   j   e  \n   a   a   f   j   e   s  \n   a
0000020 

$ hexdump -cn 32 sorted-file.txt 
0000000   a  \r  \n   a   a  \r  \n   a   a   a  \r  \n   a   a   d  \r
0000010  \n   a   a   d   s  \r  \n   a   a   f   j   e  \r  \n   a   a
0000020
```

Your sorted file is bigger because it uses Windows line endings `\r\n` (two bytes) instead of Linux line endings `\n` (one byte).

Could it be that you were running that command above under Windows using either tools like `cygwin` or this new Linux subsystem for Windows 10? Or did you maybe run something in Wine?

Comment: this new *Windows Subsystem for Linux*? bash is only one Linux program that runs in it; sort is not bash.

Comment: @immibis You mean *Linux subsystem for Windows*? I meant that, but haven't been too interested in it myself yet, so did not try or research it further so far.

Comment: It is actually called the *Windows Subsystem for Linux*, but either one makes sense. (See how this would look with another subsystem: either "Windows Subsystem for Console [Applications]" or "Console [Application] Subsystem for Windows" makes sense)

Comment: @immibis Aha, okay. You see I wasn't too interested in that specific topic yet. Forgive me, please :)